# Show/hide button javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm using php and I'm trying to retrieve some data from a db. 
Those data are a list of number with a pair of strings. 
I simply get all the data and with a for a echo-ed a series of `<tr>` elements with inside a series of `<td>` elements. 
It worked fine.

Now I'm trying to create a filter to show and hide some elements. 
For example at first I'd like to show only the odd number 
then pressing my button I'll show all the number.

Is it possible to do something like that?

Comment: post some codes what you've tried

Comment: where do you exactly have the issue? 1. Retrieving data from db? 2. Displaying them? 3. Validating them 4. Triggering button property?

Comment: The issue is that I don't know how to create a js script to show and hide only some element of my table. Because I thought to save every id of the <tr> element, but I discovered that the <tr> tag doesn't have any id! If the <tr> had an id, the solution is simply getelementbyid and setting those element with style.display = none. But <tr> doesn't have any id... =/

Comment: You can add id just fine: `<tr id="row_1">` then you can hide it with `document.getElementById("row_1").style.display = "none";`

Comment: [Don't reinvent the wheel](http://datatables.net/).

Comment: @ShadowWizard yes I'm trying to do something like this, but the problem is that I create a a new table every time, because it is possible that the db data changed, so I need to create a new id for all the new tr tag. Is this possible? Thanks

Comment: Not sure I follow, but if you mean having unique ID for the rows then add a counter variable to the loop which increase by 1 on each iteration then append its value to the ID of each row. Better yet, if you have data from database with some identifier then use that identifier instead of the loop counter.

Answer (score 3):

you can do it easily with jquery:

```
$('table tr:even').hide();
$('#button-id').click(function()
{
   $('table tr:even').show();
});
```

Comment: I don't know jquery... I'm sorry but I'm a newbie in those technologies.. Is jquery a sort of javascript library?

Comment: @MachoProgrammer yes jQuery is JavaScript library free to use which is very widely used these days on great many websites. Don't feel obliged to use it, for your needs pure JavaScript should be just enough.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not understand what are you looking for but this might be of help.

**javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#gdRows td").each(function() {
        var cellText = $(this).text();
        if ($.trim(cellText) == '') {
            $(this).css('background-color', 'cyan');
        }
    });

    $('#btnHide').click(function() {
        $("#gdRows tr td").each(function() {
            var cell = $.trim($(this).text());
            if (cell.length == 0) {
                $(this).parent().hide();
            }
        });
    });
    $('#btnReset').click(function() {
        $("#gdRows tr").each(function() {
            $(this).show();
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

**css**

```
body
{
   font-family: Calibri;
   font-size : 11pt;
   padding : 10px;
}

th
{
   font-weight:bold;
   padding:5px;
   background-color: Lightgrey;
}

table
{
    width: 450px;
}
td
{
    width:30px;
    padding:5px;
}

input
{
   font-family: Calibri;
   font-size : 12pt;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table border="1" id="gdRows">
        <tr align="left">
            <th scope="col">ID</th><th scope="col">ProductName</th><th scope="col">Quantity</th><th scope="col">Price</th><th scope="col">Description</th>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>1</td>
    <td>Mouse</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>Great Quality</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>2</td><td>Speaker</td><td>15</td><td>990</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>3</td><td>Hard Drive</td><td>35</td><td>3580</td><td>500 GB available</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>4</td><td>RAM</td><td>22</td><td>399</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>5</td><td>Keyboard</td><td>10</td><td>3500</td><td>Wireless</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>6</td><td>Wi-Fi Router</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>3990</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>7</td><td>LCD</td><td>62</td><td>3000</td><td>17 inch</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>8</td><td>Intel Processor</td><td>5</td><td>7000</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>9</td><td>HeadPhones</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>350</td><td>Great Quality</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>10</td><td>Monitor</td><td>25</td><td>1990</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
</table>
<br/>
<input type="button" id="btnHide" Value=" Hide Empty Rows " />
<input type="button" id="btnReset" Value=" Reset " />
```

Live version here: http://jsfiddle.net/jquerybyexample/4RpVv/

Comment: Ok, I need to learn jquery asap! Thanks for this example, is very helpful!